# SHChangeNotifyRegister with QT/MinGW 4.8 cannot link

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, mingw

I'm trying to implement a feature whereby USB storage devices are auto detected by my program.

I understand that I need to listen for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, and have done using a `QAbstractNativeEventFilter` but this doesn't catch a specific case which is an SD card being inserted or removed from a reader (or in my specific case pushing the "Turn on mass storage" button on my phone).

Upon some Googling I found this post: [Detect insertion of media into a drive using windows messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420131/detect-insertion-of-media-into-a-drive-using-windows-messages) which describes exactly what I need which makes use of `SHCNE_MEDIAINSERTED` and `SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED`.

**My Problem** is that my linker can't seem to find `SHChangeNotifyRegister`. Inside of Qt Creator I'm getting the code completion declarations for `slobj.h`, but upon compiling I get this:

```
error: undefined reference to `_imp__SHChangeNotifyRegister@24'
```

Then `ld` fails with exit code 1.

I'm at a loss as to what the linker cannot find, the includes are fine inside QtCreator - so can it not find `shell32.dll`? I'm running `mingw4.8 32bit` is this a case of it being unable to use a dll compiled with a different compiler? I've also tried adding `win32: LIBS += -lshell32` to my .pro file to no avail, and also added the `lib` folder of a windows 7 SDK to my path variable.

My code is as follows (note that I'm 100% useless with winapi so this code is likely massively broken as I was in the middle of tinkering with it):

```
MainWindow w(deviceMgr);
w.show();

int sources = 0x0001 | 0x0002 | 0x8000; // Interupt, Shell, New Delivery Missing Defs
LONG events = SHCNE_MEDIAINSERTED | SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED;

PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;

SHGetFolderLocation((HWND) w.winId(), CSIDL_DRIVES, NULL, 0, &pidl);

SHChangeNotifyEntry entries[] = { pidl, false };

ULONG code = SHChangeNotifyRegister(
    (HWND) w.winId(),
    sources,
    events,
    WM_APP + 1,
    ARRAYSIZE(entries),
    entries
);
```

Comments also welcome that might help me better formulate this question.

**UPDATE:**

Following Carey and Michaels suggestions in the notes I have figured out a few things:

- I'm not using the shell32.lib from the Windows SDK because I think that is for MSVC.
- mingw links against its own shell32.a
- Having used `objdump -x shell32.a` from my mingw distribution I can find no reference to SHChangeNotifyRegister.
- Using `objdump -x shell32.lib` on the `shell32.lib` from the windows SDK I can find the line:

  ```
  [  3](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __imp__SHChangeNotifyRegister@24
  ```

This makes me believe that the shell32.a distributed with mingw 4.8 is incomplete and therefore my program will not link.

So I think I shall explore either a more recent version of mingw *if* one exists OR linking against the WindowsSDK with mingw which I believe is impossible OR using MSVC for my windows builds.

So therefore I think the answer to my question is: "It doesn't link because your shell32.a doesn't contain everything in the .h"?

**ANSWER:**

Turns out mingw can use certain msvc .lib files. So this time I linked properly to the Windows SDK version of shell32.lib and everything seems to work. In short this needed to be added to my `.pro` file:

```
win32: LIBS += -L"C:/Path/To/Microsoft/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/" -lshell32
```

Comment: Linkage failures like that usually mean you got a function argument, return type or calling convention wrong.

Comment: It sounds that either you dont link with Shell32.lib for some reason or that your Shell32.lib doesn't export the _SHChangeNotifyRegister@24 function. Try to find the Shell32.lib file, type "dumpbin /exports shell32.lib" at a command prompt and look if the _SHChangeNotifyRegister@24 function is exported

Comment: Ok, I think those replies have got me little closer to understanding what is going on. I'm going to update the question and perhaps one of you could put your message as an answer because I think I will accept one. If I've gotten the wrong end of the stick then please say so in the messages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that I can accept an answer on this question I'll post up the solution here.

Reading Carey and Michael's comments on the question gave me the a clue as to what was wrong.

> It sounds that either you dont link with Shell32.lib for some reason or that your Shell32.lib doesn't export the _SHChangeNotifyRegister@24 function. Try to find the Shell32.lib file, type "dumpbin /exports shell32.lib" at a command prompt and look if the _SHChangeNotifyRegister@24 function is exported

Essentially the `shell32.a` that mingw was linking against lacked the definition of `SHChangeNotifyRegister` (the mingw version of `shlobj.h` had this declaration) - you can read how I came to that conclusion in the updates of the question.

To fix the solution I used a copy of `shell32.lib` from a Windows SDK that I had laying around - I think this can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8279). Luckily mingw could link that .lib file.

To link the new `shell32.lib` with my QT Qbuild `.pro` file I used the following:

```
win32: LIBS += -L"C:/Path/To/Microsoft/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/" -lshell32
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error while trying to compile an app. I wanted to have Qt Creator build with the MSVC 2013 toolkit. I had `LIBS += -ladvapi32` in my `.pro` file but was still getting:

```
FilePathUtilities.obj : error LNK2019: 
unresolved external symbol __imp_ShellExecuteExW 
referenced in function "void __cdecl FileShowInExplorer(class CStr const &,int)"
```

The problem ended up to be simply: I was building with the x64 MSVC toolkit instead of the 32 bit toolkit!

I don't know why, I'm not a C++ dev, but it looks like the 32 and 64 bit identifiers aren't identical:

```
/* 32 BIT LIBRARY */
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Lib
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe" -exports shell32.lib | grep ShellEx
                  _WOWShellExecute@28
                  _ShellExecuteW@24
                  _ShellExecuteExW@4
                  _ShellExecuteExA@4
                  _ShellExecuteEx@4
                  _ShellExecuteA@24


/* 64 BIT LIBRARY */
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Lib/x64
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\dumpbin.exe" -exports shell32.lib | grep ShellEx
                  ShellExecuteA
                  ShellExecuteEx
                  ShellExecuteExA
                  ShellExecuteExW
                  ShellExecuteW
                  WOWShellExecute
```