# C++ Linux to Windows Cross-compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a C++ program for windows in linux. This program uses the SHGetKnownFolderPath function. Whenever I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp main.h -mwindows -o main.exe
/tmp/cc7yIaVK.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `SHGetKnownFolderPath'
/tmp/cc7yIaVK.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.FOLDERID_Startup[.refptr.FOLDERID_Startup]+0x0): undefined reference to `FOLDERID_Startup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd){
    //get startup folder
    if(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Startup, 0, NULL, &startupFolder) != S_OK){
        //error in getting startup folder
        return -1;
    }
  /*
  ...
  */
}
```

I included the proper header files and defined the windows version:

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <shlobj.h>
```

EDIT: I learned that I have to link a lib file in the compilation, presumably with the -l flag after the source file names, according to mingw.org documentation. I don't know what the name of the file I need is though.

I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: The `#include`s and `#define`s are only interesting for the compilation time.  You've got no compilation error but a linker error.  So you need to figure out what you've got to link along with your stuff in order to provide the linker with what it needs.  Does https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/112 help?

Comment: @Alfe I saw that link on google as well but it doesn't work. Apparently there is a DDoS attack on these sites right now: http://www.pcworld.com/article/3133847/internet/ddos-attack-on-dyn-knocks-spotify-twitter-github-etsy-and-more-offline.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHChangeNotifyRegister with QT/MinGW 4.8 cannot link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048068/shchangenotifyregister-with-qt-mingw-4-8-cannot-link)

Comment: @krOoze that post talks about Qt (which I am not using) and Windows  (which I am not using)(guessing from the DOS-style path in the answer). The solution provided by that post does not apply here.

Comment: @Yapoz Very well. Nevertheless the function seems to be in `shell32` which needs to be linked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A quick find/nm (with a suitable nm that recognizes Windows binaries)0 gives:

```
rich@dev:~/ellcc-release/libecc/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32$ find . -name "*.a" | xargs ~/ellcc/bin/ecc-nm -A | grep FOLDERID_Startup
/home/rich/ellcc/bin/ecc-nm: ./sys-root/mingw/lib/libruntimeobject.a: File format not recognized
./sys-root/mingw/lib/libuuid.a:lib64_libuuid_a-uuid.o:0000000000000000 r .rdata$FOLDERID_Startup
./sys-root/mingw/lib/libuuid.a:lib64_libuuid_a-uuid.o:0000000000000000 R FOLDERID_Startup
rich@dev:~/ellcc-release/libecc/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32$
```

It looks as if -luuid is what you need.

I made a little test program:

```
rich@dev:~$ cat win.c 
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <shlobj.h>
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd){
    const char *startupFolder;
    //get startup folder
    if(SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Startup, 0, NULL, &startupFolder) != S_OK){
        //error in getting startup folder
        return -1;
    }
  /*
  ...
  */
}

rich@dev:~$ ~/ellcc/bin/ecc -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 win.c -luuid
win.c:7:57: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'const char **' to
      parameter of type 'PWSTR *' (aka 'unsigned short **')
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if(SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Startup, 0, NULL, &startupFolder) != S...
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/rich/ellcc/bin/../libecc/mingw/include/shlobj.h:746:92: note: passing
      argument to parameter 'ppszPath' here
  ...(REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid, DWORD dwFlags, HANDLE hToken, PWSTR *ppszPath);
                                                                  ^
1 warning generated.
rich@dev:~$
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. -luuid seems to fix the FOLDERID_Startup problem, but I still get the undefined reference to `SHGetKnownFolderPath` in my errors. I would have thought that this would be fixed by the same solution. It complains about it in here: `/tmp/cc5KqFce.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x150)` rather than giving a line on main.cpp, so I think this is another linker error.

Comment: That symbol is defined in libshell32.a. My clang/mingw includes that by default, sorry. Adding -lshell32 should fix it.

Comment: nope, same error. -lshell32 seems to not do anything while -luuid removes 1 out of 2 errors, if that helps at all.

Comment: That's strange, if I remove it from the default library list, the link fails, but this line works: ~/ellcc/bin/ecc -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 win.c -luuid -lshell32

Comment: maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm using C++ instead of C? Here is my line (which does not work) if it matters: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp main.h -luuid -lshell32 -o main.exe`

Comment: That is exactly right. It fails if I compile the main file with C++. My guess is that there isn't a proper extern "C" declaration of SHGetKnownFolderPath. Maybe you're missing an #include that defines it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126478/discussion-between-yapoz-and-richard-pennington).