# Detecting if a sd card reader has a card inserted

Tags: c, windows, winapi, sd-card, ada

Does anyone know how to use the Windows Api in C to detect whether an SD Card reader has a card inserted or not?

Platform: windows xp/visa/7/8.

I've had a google around and a look at the Windows API Doc (which i'm unfamiliar with so probably missed a lot) and have been unable to find an answer.

I've had a look at this post [How can I detect when an SD card is plugged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583593/how-can-i-detect-when-an-sd-card-is-plugged-in) - which was close but didn't give me what i needed as i don't want to detect a change in state, rather what state it is in at the time of query.

(If by blind chance someone has an Ada implementation of this, that would be amazing, otherwise i plan to just link with C)

Thank you for any help

Matt

Comment: AFAIK there is not such API but you may check if a drive is _ready_ (then if there is a formatted card inside) trying to read file attributes (with [`GetFileAttributesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946(v=vs.85).aspx)) for root directory (such as "D:\"). If it returns `FALSE` then you can check `GetLastError()` error code (just try which one is returned for "drive not ready").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this using windows api call GetVolumeInformation which returns 0 if the drive is not ready.
The advantage of using GetVolumeInformation over GetFileAttributes was that GetVolumeInformation is silent, where as GetFileAttributes will cause windows to popup a box saying the drive is empty if it can't find the file. There may be a cleaner way of doing this - but this is working for me now :)

Thank you for the help!